# Android downloading progressbar whole on listview items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i'm writing simple listview as an download list and user can click on that to download it. i dont have any problem to download file with service from internet, but after visible progressbar on list view item. thats show whole listview and i can not handle that to dont show whole listview and only show progressbar on clicked listview's item to download.

My adapter :

```
public void fillItems(final AdapterMessageContent adapter, final MessagesList item, final int position) {
    stream_url = item.getStream_link().split("/");
    stream_filename = stream_url[stream_url.length - 1];

    File file = new File(G.dir_image + "/" + stream_filename);
    if (item.getMsg_type() != 0) {
        if (!file.exist()) {
            Log.e("", "visible downloader icon");
            UI.imgv_image_item.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(G.dir_app + "/" + "thumbs/" + item.getPreview_image_url()));

            /* SET tag to handle this listview item */
            UI.npb_progressbar.setTag(item.getId());

            UI.iv_download_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            UI.iv_download_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    UI.ll_handle_progress_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    item.setDownload_status(1);
                    G.DOWNLOADLIST.create(new DownloadTaskList(item.getMsg_id(), 0, item.getStream_link(), 0, 0, 0, position));
                    G.context.startService(new Intent(G.currentActivity, ServiceMultiTaskDownloader.class).putExtra("download_item_id", item.getMsg_id()));
                    UI.npb_progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    UI.tv_downloding_file_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        } if (UI.npb_progressbar.getTag().equals(item.getId())) {
            UI.imgv_image_item.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(G.dir_app + "/" + item.getPreview_image_url()));

            /* HIDE icon to disable click by user to download file */
            UI.iv_download_icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

now out of this Adapter i can update row by simple BroadCastReceiver:

```
private void updateView(int position, int file_size, int downloaded_size, int percent, String stream_filename) {
    View v = UI.lv_message_content.getChildAt(position - UI.lv_message_content.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    UI.lv_message_content.getAdapter().getView(position, v, UI.lv_message_content);
    UI.lv_message_content.invalidateViews();
    if (v == null) return;

    ImageView         imgv_image_item         = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgv_image_item);
    NumberProgressBar numberProgressBar       = (NumberProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.npb_progressbar);
    TextView          tv_downloding_file_info = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_downloding_file_info);

    if (numberProgressBar.getTag() != null && numberProgressBar.getTag().equals(messagesLists.get(position).getId())) {
        numberProgressBar.setProgress(percent);

        tv_downloding_file_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv_downloding_file_info.setText(UC.convertByteToMB(downloaded_size) + "/" + UC.convertByteToMB(file_size));

        if (percent == 100) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 30;
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(G.dir_image + "/" + stream_filename);
            imgv_image_item.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            tv_downloding_file_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            numberProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

unfortunately when downloading file by click on `UI.iv_download_icon` my listview item repeate on position 0 and position 6.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @Zharf unfortunately when downloading file by click on `UI.iv_download_icon` my progressBar on listview item repeate on position 0 and position 6.

Comment: So when you start a download and scroll down the list you find another progress bar on an item that's not supposed to have it?

Comment: @Zharf yes sir, i can not handle that to dont show and find correctly who item must be show progressbar

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, and reading the code carefully, I think this is a case of misunderstanding how `Adapters` and `ListView` (or `RecyclerView`) work.

`ListView` and the new `RecyclerView` *recycle* the views that they show, in order to minimize memory footprint and view creation overhead. To make it seem like there's hundreds of views in the list, they employ `Adapters` to create a few views (enough to fill the area taken by the list) and then update content of a view as it's time to show the item to the user.

If you bypass the logic of the `Adapter` and modify the contents of a view that belongs to the `Adapter`, you will cause the same changes to seemingly random items up or down the list because of this recycling that happens.

The way to solve this is to do the view updates in `getView` method of the `Adapter` (or `onBindViewHolder` of `RecyclerView.Adapter`). The `Adapter` should have an internal list of data that you can use to decide what the view should look like. You can then modify the data and call `notifyDataSetChanged` (there are other options when using `RecyclerView.Adapter`) which causes `getView` to be called for each item that needs an update (are visible on the screen).

Moral of the story: never do view updates directly to the views in a list, modify the data in the `Adapter` instead and inform it that the data has changed so it knows that it should do view updates to show up-to-date data.